# IBM Cloud Storage SDK Java Error en ClientConfiguration

Tags: java, cloud, jackson

De antemano gracias por la ayuda. Estoy usando el SDK de Ibm Cloud Storage y al momento de crear la instancia del cliente me falla en la línea:

```
ClientConfiguration clientConfig = new ClientConfiguration()
                        .withRequestTimeout(5000)
                        .withTcpKeepAlive(true);
```

el log muestra el siguiente error:

```
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/std/StdDeserializer._parseDate(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationContext;)Ljava/util/Date; @77: astore
  Reason:
    Type 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParseException' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/exc/StreamReadException' (stack map, stack[0])
  Current Frame:
    bci: @69
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/std/StdDeserializer', 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser', 'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationContext' }
    stack: { 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParseException' }
  Stackmap Frame:
    bci: @77
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/std/StdDeserializer', 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser', 'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationContext' }
    stack: { 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/exc/StreamReadException' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2bb6 0035 aa00 0000 0000 0081 0000 0003
    0000010: 0000 000b 0000 007a 0000 0081 0000 0081
    0000020: 0000 0034 0000 0041 0000 0081 0000 0081
    0000030: 0000 0081 0000 0071 2a2b b600 11b6 0012
    0000040: 2cb6 006b b02b b600 4742 a700 223a 052c
    0000050: 2ab4 0002 2bb6 006e 126f 03bd 0004 b600
    0000060: 70c0 002d 3a06 1906 b600 4c42 bb00 7159
    0000070: 21b7 0072 b02a 2cb6 0073 c000 71b0 2a2b
    0000080: 2cb6 0074 b02c 2ab4 0002 2bb6 0025 c000
    0000090: 71b0                                   
  Exception Handler Table:
    bci [69, 74] => handler: 77
    bci [69, 74] => handler: 77
  Stackmap Table:
    same_frame(@56)
    same_frame(@69)
    same_locals_1_stack_item_frame(@77,Object[#367])
    append_frame(@108,Long)
    chop_frame(@117,1)
    same_frame(@126)
    same_frame(@133)

    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JdkDeserializers.<clinit>(JdkDeserializers.java:26)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.findDefaultDeserializer(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:1852)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.findStdDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:167)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.createBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:131)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer2(DeserializerCache.java:411)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:349)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:264)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:476)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(ObjectMapper.java:4389)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4198)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3136)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.internal.config.InternalConfig.loadfrom(InternalConfig.java:236)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.internal.config.InternalConfig.load(InternalConfig.java:249)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.internal.config.InternalConfig$Factory.<clinit>(InternalConfig.java:304)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.util.VersionInfoUtils.userAgent(VersionInfoUtils.java:142)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.util.VersionInfoUtils.initializeUserAgent(VersionInfoUtils.java:137)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.util.VersionInfoUtils.getUserAgent(VersionInfoUtils.java:100)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.ClientConfiguration.<clinit>(ClientConfiguration.java:78)
    at eidypymesRest.utils.UploadCloudStorage.createClient(UploadCloudStorage.java:127)
    at eidypymesRest.utils.UploadAsync.run(UploadAsync.java:56)
```

He intentado cambiar la versión del la librería Jackson pero no ha funcionado.

Estoy usando

Tomcat 9, JDK 11.0.11 y todas estas librerias para el SDK de IBM:

- commons-codec-1.15.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
- httpclient-4.5.13.jar
- httpcore-4.4.13.jar
- ibm-cos-java-sdk-core-2.10.1.jar
- ibm-cos-java-sdk-kms-2.10.1.jar
- ibm-cos-java-sdk-s3-2.10.1.jar
- ion-java-1.2.0.jar
- jackson-annotations-2.12.0.jar
- jackson-core-2.12.0.jar
- jackson-databind-2.12.0.jar
- jackson-dataformat-cbor-2.12.1.jar
- javax.annotation-api-1.3.1.jar
- jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar
- jaxb-core-2.3.0.jar
- jaxb-impl-2.3.0.jar
- joda-time-2.8.2.jar

Gracias.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado. EL problema es que algunos jars se estaban empaquetando en el archivo war y presentaban conflictos con los jars que ya estaban el la carpeta lib del tomcat. Generé el war nuevamente sin incluir los jars.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).